# Animate part of title when mouse is over

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to animate a title composed of two part: "HARD" and "WARE", the second one has a more transparent color.

When the mouse is over the "HARD" word the colors are reversed correctly but when the mouse is over the "WARE" word this doesn't happen, only one color changes.
I have already tried to use the combinators selector but there is no selector for the "previous siblings".

```css
body {
  background-color: #171717;
}

#title {
  font-size: 10vmax;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Calibri;
}

#hard {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#hard:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18);
}

#hard:hover + #ware {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

#ware {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#ware:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

#title span:last-child:hover + #title > span:first-child {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18);
}
```

```html
<div id="title">
  <span id="hard">HARD</span>
  <span id="ware">WARE</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution which uses the `:hover` state of the *parent* element in two rules which have combined selectors with the first and last child:

```css
body {
  background-color: #171717;
}

#title {
  font-size: 10vmax;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Calibri;
}

#hard {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#ware {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#title:hover span:first-child {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18);
}

#title:hover span:last-child {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id="title">
  <span id="hard">HARD</span>
  <span id="ware">WARE</span>
</div>
```

Addition: Instead of first and last child you could also use the IDs in the selectors:

```css
body {
  background-color: #171717;
}

#title {
  font-size: 10vmax;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Calibri;
}

#hard {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#ware {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#title:hover #hard {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18);
}

#title:hover #ware {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id="title">
  <span id="hard">HARD</span>
  <span id="ware">WARE</span>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a solution without #title:hover?

Comment: Well, the sibling selectors (`+` and `~`) only work for *subsequent* siblings, so there is no possibility in CSS to select the *previous* sibling, as you tried. But you *can* do it with Javascript/jQuery.

Comment: thanks @johannes

Answer (score 0):

here is correction you forgot to change the opacity when "ware" was hover except that everything is right

```
#hard:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18);
}

#hard:hover + #ware {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

#ware {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#ware:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18);
}

#ware:hover + #hard{
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    
}
```

here's your code